# Looking for a linq solution to replace a for-loop

Tags: c#, linq

I run into examples like this all the time.  In this case I want to populate a stringbuilder with a new line for each FileInfo object in a previously loaded variable called **files**, that of course contains a bunch of FileInfo objects.  For the first object, I want to add **FIRST** after the text then for everything else I want to add **NOTFIRST**.  To do this with a forloop, I have to setup a counter, do an if statement and increment the counter.

I've learned just enough linq that its on the tip of my fingers, but I know there has to be an *elegant* LINQ solution.

```
            var mysb = new StringBuilder();
            var count = 0;
            string extra;
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                var newLine = fi.Name;
                if (count == 0)
                    extra = "FIRST";
                else
                    extra= "NOTFIRST";
                count = count++;
                mysb.AppendLine(string.Format("({0} {1})", newLine, extra));
            }
```

Comment: What's your sample input and output?

Comment: sample input is a list of files [A, B, C] and output is a stringbuilder with (A FIRST), (B NOTFIRST) etc.  Cheesy example, but it would take too long to explain the real application area

Comment: You must have **several** test cases, before you apply your code to the real area. Otherwise you can't really verify what you developed is what you really wanted. The more specific you are with requirements, the better quality help you will receive on StackOverflow. As an added benefit, you will also find yourself rewriting your code less often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the overload of Select that gives you the current index: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx

I also don't like mutating state when using linq so I would use String.Join instead.

```
mysb.AppendLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    files.Select((fi, i) => String.Format(fi.Name, i == 0 ? "FIRST" : "NOTFIRST"))));
```

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would forego the LINQ and stick with what you have, just simpler:

```
var mysb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
    string extra = mysb.Length == 0 ? "FIRST" : "NOTFIRST";
    mysb.Append(fi.Name);
    mysb.AppendLine(extra);
}
```

(It's not clear to me why you are treating the file name as a valid format string...of course, if it really *is* a valid format string, you can change my two calls to `Append()` and `AppendLine()` back to the single call with the `string.Format()`)

Comment: I find it counterintutive. What does mysb.Length has to do with the fact that the file is first in collection? It's relying on some implementation detail. Just my opinion of course :)

Comment: Actually, it has _everything_ to do with what the actual goal here is: to use the word "FIRST" in the first line of text added to the `StringBuilder` instance (i.e. before anything else has been added to it). It is IMHO much more directly connected to the intent, and doesn't require extra object instances, method calls, and variables.

Comment: I need the selector to be dependent upon the first item, not the length.. ah nvm.  I see what you did there.

Comment: I would remove the condition inside the loop. If there are numerous files it is a waste of time to repeat the same test for all the files but the first. Of course this is true also for the original question

Comment: @Steve: "waste of time" implies that you could measure the difference. An extra conditional jump to select one literal versus another is not going to show up in _any_ performance profile, especially where you're dealing with an enumerator and either two calls to append text or a call to `string.Format()`. The array re-allocation alone in `StringBuilder` will completely swamp any performance issue, especially since the alternative is to keep a local outside the loop and assign it at the end (i.e. the assignment isn't free either).

Comment: If it's a non-linq solution I would just prefer the for loop - it will allow me to get rid of awkward count variable. I believe the linq solution expresses what should be done not how. And imho the _what_ is: the first element should be marked as first and every other element should be marked as notfirst. Everything else is just formatting the output.

Comment: @empi: There is no `count` variable in the above code.

Comment: To be fair, this is far easier to read.  But since I asked for a linq version, I'm going to select the answer below.

Comment: @PeterDuniho right right it is not really measurable in any reality frame of reference. Just a rethorically point. I like this kind of approach

Comment: @Neolisk: the following code got rid of count because it checks the mysb.Length which is even less intuitive for me. It's not a rant :) I see we just have other views on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As often as it happens I ask questions here, I went with a hybrid of suggetsions:

```
            foreach (var fi in files)
            {
                var extra = (fi == files.First() ? "FIRST" : "NOTFIRST");
                sb.AppendLine(fi.Name + extra);
            }
```

I was unwilling to check the length of the stringbuilder, because I have other scenarios where **extra**  pretty much requires using a linq function.

I suppose I could have just as easily done the following (for my stated example):

```
            sb.AppendLine(files.First().Name + " FIRST");
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            files.Skip(1).Select( fi => fi.Name + " NOTFIRST")));
```

But to be honest, its half as readable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting that this is the best way to do this, but it was fun to write:

```
var fi = new [] { new  { Name= "A"},
                  new  { Name= "B"}, 
                  new  { Name= "C"}};

String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
        fi.Take(1).Select (f => Tuple.Create(f.Name,"FIRST"))
.Concat(fi.Skip(1).Select (f => Tuple.Create(f.Name,"NONFIRST")))
.Select(t=> String.Format("({0} {1})", t.Item1, t.Item2)))
.Dump();
```